# Clear not-an-answer flags as helpful when a flagged post is deleted through the review queue

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, flags, review, not-an-answer

Right now some answers are deleted neither "by the owner" nor "by <some diamond>" - most likely via the "Recommend deletion" function of the new review queue.

However, when a post is deleted like that any flags on it remain intact. Not-an-answer flags should be cleared (as helpful) in this case.